# How do I initialize the properties of a Matlab object?

Tags: matlab

I would like to specify my own camera parameters by creating an instance of the cameraParameters [cameraParameters](http://www.mathworks.com/help/vision/ref/cameraparameters-class.html) class in Matlab. However, I don't quite understand the syntax for initializing such a structure with my own intrinsic and extrinsic matrix.

My question is, how do I initialize an instance of a cameraParameters instance with my own values?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the link that you supplied, you can see that properties are supplied using `Name, Value` pairs. These are fairly common in MATLAB.

Let's say that we wanted to set the intrinsic matrix. We would do this with the following code,

```
cameraParams = cameraParameters('IntrinsicMatrix', I);
```

where `I` is the 3x3 identity matrix for the projection matrix.